# How to add a dataframe to a dataframe for every iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a folder which contains json files, every json file represents a drink. The files all look like below, they just have a different prize output. Below is the json file of `coffee.json`:

```
{
    "data": {
        "start_date": "2022-10-01",
        "end_date": "2022-10-04",
        "cur": "EUR",
        "prizes": {
            "2022-10-01": {
                "coffee": 0.1448939471560284
            },
            "2022-10-02": {
                "coffee": 0.14487923291390148
            },
            "2022-10-03": {
                "coffee": 0.1454857922753868
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to grab the first `json file` and create a `dataframe` of it, after that I want to grab the second `json file` and add only the column `prizes` to the first `df`, and grab the third `json file` and again add the `prizes` column etc.

**This is what I tried:**

```
base_path = r'C:\Users\Geo\Desktop\python-exer\json_files'

drinks_list = ['soda', 'water', 'coffee', 'coke', 'fanta']

for file in os.listdir(base_path):
    file_without_ext = file.split('.')[0]

    #check if file occurs in drinks_list
    if file_without_ext in drinks_list:
        with open(base_path +  '/' + file,'r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
    
        df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']['prizes']).T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'date'}).assign(cur=data['data']['cur'])
        print(df)

        if df.columns[1] != 'coffee':
            df.join(df[file_without_ext],  how='left', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
        
        print(df)
```

**This is my output:**

```
         date    coffee cur
0  2022-10-01  0.06889  EUR
1  2022-10-02  0.06287  EUR
2  2022-10-03  0.07864  EUR
         date      soda cur
0  2022-10-01  0.94444  EUR
1  2022-10-02  0.86877  EUR
2  2022-10-03  0.68972  EUR
         date     water cur
0  2022-10-01  0.98751  EUR
1  2022-10-02  0.87982  EUR
2  2022-10-03  0.56677  EUR
         date     water cur
0  2022-10-01  0.98751  EUR
1  2022-10-02  0.87982  EUR
2  2022-10-03  0.56677  EUR
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
         date    coffee     soda        water      cur
0  2022-10-01  0.06889      0.94444     0.98751    EUR
1  2022-10-02  0.06287      0.86877     0.87982    EUR
2  2022-10-03  0.07864      0.68972     0.56677    EUR
```

Comment: There is always `EUR` ?

Comment: Yes there is always EUR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `DataFrame`s with `MultiIndex` by `date`s and currency, then append to list `dfs` and last join by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
base_path = r'C:\Users\Geo\Desktop\python-exer\json_files'

drinks_list = ['soda', 'water', 'coffee', 'coke', 'fanta']

dfs= []

for file in os.listdir(base_path):
    file_without_ext = file.split('.')[0]

    #check if file occurs in drinks_list
    if file_without_ext in drinks_list:
        with open(base_path +  '/' + file,'r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']['prizes']).T.assign(cur = data['data']['cur']).set_index('cur', append=True)
            dfs.append(df)
            
final = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index()
```

If there is always same currency, solution is simplier - last assign column currency:

```
base_path = r'C:\Users\Geo\Desktop\python-exer\json_files'
drinks_list = ['soda', 'water', 'coffee', 'coke', 'fanta']
dfs= []

for file in os.listdir(base_path):
    file_without_ext = file.split('.')[0]

    #check if file occurs in drinks_list
    if file_without_ext in drinks_list:
        with open(base_path +  '/' + file,'r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']['prizes']).T
            
            cur = data['data']['cur']
            dfs.append(df)
            
final = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index().assign(cur=cur)
```

Test first solution:

```
d1 = {
    "data": {
        "start_date": "2022-10-01",
        "end_date": "2022-10-04",
        "cur": "EUR",
        "prizes": {
            "2022-10-01": {
                "coffee": 0.1448939471560284
            },
            "2022-10-02": {
                "coffee": 0.14487923291390148
            },
            "2022-10-03": {
                "coffee": 0.1454857922753868
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
d2 = {
    "data": {
        "start_date": "2022-10-01",
        "end_date": "2022-10-04",
        "cur": "EUR",
        "prizes": {
            "2022-10-01": {
                "water": 0.7448939471560284
            },
            "2022-10-02": {
                "water": 0.74487923291390148
            },
            "2022-10-03": {
                "water": 0.7454857922753868
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
d3 = {
    "data": {
        "start_date": "2022-10-01",
        "end_date": "2022-10-04",
        "cur": "EUR",
        "prizes": {
            "2022-10-01": {
                "fanta": 0.88939471560284
            },
            "2022-10-02": {
                "fanta": 0.9923291390148
            },
            "2022-10-03": {
                "fanta": 0.957922753868
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
dfs= []

for d in [d1, d2, d3]:
    data = d
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']['prizes']).T.assign(cur = data['data']['cur']).set_index('cur', append=True)
    dfs.append(df)
    
final = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).rename_axis(('date','cur')).reset_index()
print (final)
         date  cur    coffee     water     fanta
0  2022-10-01  EUR  0.144894  0.744894  0.889395
1  2022-10-02  EUR  0.144879  0.744879  0.992329
2  2022-10-03  EUR  0.145486  0.745486  0.957923
```

And second solution:

```
dfs= []

for d in [d1, d2, d3]:
    data = d
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']['prizes']).T
    cur = data['data']['cur']
    dfs.append(df)
    
final = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).rename_axis('date').reset_index().assign(cur=cur)
print (final)
         date    coffee     water     fanta  cur
0  2022-10-01  0.144894  0.744894  0.889395  EUR
1  2022-10-02  0.144879  0.744879  0.992329  EUR
2  2022-10-03  0.145486  0.745486  0.957923  EUR
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation? If I run your code I get data values under cur

Comment: @Erling_Haaland - What line failed?

Comment: @Erling_Haaland - I found typo, need change `data['data']['cur']` to `data['data']['prizes']` for `currency`, answer was edited, added sample data